# removeFromParent() on ListItem removes the wrong item

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Doc I'm attempting to edit programmatically, and it contains a couple lists. So for instance I have a list like this:

- Main List 1

  - Sub-list 1
  - Sub-list 2
- Main List 2

  - Sub-list 3
  - Sub-list 4
  - Sub-list 5
- Main List 3

What I'm trying to do is delete sub-list 5 by finding the text then removing it from the parent. The code I'm using for this is like so:

```
var subList = checklistBody.findText("Sub-list 5");
var subElement = checklistBody.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM, subList);
subElement.getElement().removeFromParent();
```

Strangely what happens here though is Main List 3 gets deleted. If I replace the findText statement to find the text for "Sub-List 4," it will select and remove the item for Sub-List 5. So basically it always appears to be removing the next element instead of the one where the text was found.

Is this a bug? Or what am I missing about how selecting list items should work? Thanks!

Comment: You can open an issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) to report this.

Comment: Thanks @noogui. I will do that if no one can point out something I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `subList` should already be pointing to the element you want to remove. Your call to `findElement()` is finding the next list item after "Sub-list 5", which is "Mail List 3".